# Python3 executes terminal differently than manual input

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, python-3.6

I have a small piece of python3 code. Which runs a command from the terminal.

```
import os
os.system('"C:/directory/program.exe" -k "C:/directory/options.txt" & pause')
```

When I run this code in IDLE, I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Both of the paths are valid. So thats not the problem. In addition, running:

```
"C:/directory/program.exe" -k "C:/directory/options.txt" & pause
```

from the terminal works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around the system paths, this should work:

```
import os
os.system("C:/directory/program.exe -k C:/directory/options.txt & pause")
```

Hopefully that helps.

**[Edit]** Working with spaces like you're doing it with `os.system` is to my knowledge impossible, referring to this [python bug tracker thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue1524)

A solution might be using the  [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module insead.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:/direc tory/program.exe", "-k", "C:/direc tory/program.exe"])
```

Comment: @JulianLachniet It does not, I've updated the answer.